# Adding a navigation controller to WebView

Tags: webview, swift3

I've created a WebView with:

```
var webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
```

The problem is that theres no navigation so I cannot go back or close the webview if they decide not to "login" with instagram.

So how do I add a navigation bar programmatically ? Or should I open a new view controller when the login button is pressed and then do everything in that controller?

Sincerely,

Denis Angell

Comment: Are you adding webview in the viewcontroller?

Comment: Adding a webview? I use the code above to "attach" the webview to the current view controller. Is this a bad way? If I created a whole new view controller and added a webview, would this be a better way?

Comment: Ok than what you need is that you have to embed the current controller into NavigationController